# Data Management Gateway in Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, ml-studio

I built an experiment in Azure ML Studio and want to get the input to the model through On-Premise SQL-Server Database. Does Data Management Gateway help in connecting to the Database, if so can you please mention the steps to be followed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to use Data Management Gateway.
Refer link below
[Connect to DB from ML Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio/use-data-from-an-on-premises-sql-server)